# Bigquery query JOIN unusually slow

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run this query but it is, to my limited level of comprehension, absurdingly slow.

Here is the query :

```
    SELECT
       STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(req.date, "%Y-%m-%d") AS day,
       HOUR(req.date) AS hour,
       10000*(COUNT(req.request_id) - COUNT(resp.request_id)) AS nb_bid_requests,
       COUNT(resp.request_id) AS nb_bid_responses,
   FROM
      [server.Request] req
   LEFT JOIN EACH
      server.Response resp
   ON
      req.request_id = resp.request_id
   WHERE
      DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), req.date) < 3
   GROUP EACH BY
      day,
      hour
   ORDER BY
      day,
      hour
```

What bugs me the most is that this exact same query works perfectly fine on the Production project which has the same datasets, tables and fields (with the same data types and names). The only difference is that the Production has more data than the Dev.

I'm not in any case an expert in SQL and I'd enjoy to be told where I could improve the query.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Hi, solved the issue.
      It was caused by a great number of request_id being duplicates in server.Response which slowed "a little bit" the query.

Comment: Statistics differences? How much more date (compared to dev)? Times 2, times 10, times 100 or even more?

Comment: Well in prod, you run on our system, which makes heavy use of our infrastructure. When you run on Dev, you simulate the same, but with your own computer. This is likely what happens here. (assuming by dev you mean local development server, of course, and not just a different environment)

Comment: Give us some numbers, how big is the data, duration of the query, output size, how often you run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pushing your `WHERE` clause down inside the join.

BigQuery's optimizer does not (yet) push predicates inside joins, so the query you posted joins *all* of your data and then filters it, instead of just joining the parts you care about. If you have a `date` field on both request and response, put filters on both sides of the join!

If you can't filter both sides of the join, then switch sides so that the smaller (filtered) table is on the right. Because of how BQ joins are implemented, they typically perform better if the smaller table is on the right.

```
SELECT
   STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(req.date, "%Y-%m-%d") AS day,
   HOUR(req.date) AS hour,
   10000*(COUNT(req.request_id) - COUNT(resp.request_id)) AS nb_bid_requests,
   COUNT(resp.request_id) AS nb_bid_responses,
FROM
    server.Response resp
RIGHT JOIN EACH
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            [server.Request]
        WHERE
            DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), date) < 3
    ) req
ON
   req.request_id = resp.request_id
GROUP EACH BY
   day,
   hour
ORDER BY
   day,
   hour
```